# Как указать минимальный размер QTableView, чтобы столбцы не обрезались?

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, qt5, pyqt5

Код:

---

### init_db.py

Инициализирует тестовые таблицы для работы

```py
import sqlite3
from hashlib import sha256
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

def init_tables():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("users.sqlite")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    query = """
    CREATE TABLE users(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        username TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        password_hash TEXT CHECK(LENGTH(password_hash) == 64) NOT NULL DEFAULT "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855"
    );
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    query = """
    CREATE TABLE privileges(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        username TEXT,
        privilege TEXT CHECK(privilege IN ("SELECT",  "INSERT", "UPDATE", "DELETE")) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (username)
            REFERENCES users (username)
                ON DELETE RESTRICT
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()

    connection = sqlite3.connect("data.sqlite")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;"
    cursor.execute(query)
    query = """
    CREATE TABLE people(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        full_name TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
        telephone VARCHAR(12) UNIQUE
    );
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    query = """
    CREATE TABLE addresses(
        id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        user_id INT NOT NULL,
        street VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        city VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        state VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
            REFERENCES people (id)
                ON DELETE RESTRICT
                ON UPDATE CASCADE
    );
    """
    cursor.execute(query)
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def init_users():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("users.sqlite")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    query = "INSERT INTO users (username, password_hash) VALUES (?, ?);"
    cursor.execute(query, ("admin", sha256(b"admin").hexdigest()))
    cursor.execute(query, ("viewer", sha256(b"viewer").hexdigest()))
    query = "INSERT INTO privileges (username, privilege) VALUES (?, ?);"
    cursor.execute(query, ("admin", "SELECT"))
    cursor.execute(query, ("admin", "INSERT"))
    cursor.execute(query, ("admin", "UPDATE"))
    cursor.execute(query, ("admin", "DELETE"))
    cursor.execute(query, ("viewer", "SELECT"))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def init_data():
    connection = sqlite3.connect("data.sqlite")
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    for i in range(1, 6):
        r = requests.get("https://fakepersongenerator.com/?new=fresh")
        soup = BS(r.text, "lxml")
        name = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"}).contents[1].text
        phone = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"}).contents[5].contents[1].text
        query = "INSERT INTO people (full_name, telephone) VALUES (?, ?);"
        cursor.execute(query, (name, phone))
        street = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"}).contents[3].contents[1].text
        city, state = soup.find("div", {"class": "col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12"}).contents[4].contents[1].text.split(", ")[:2]
        query = "INSERT INTO addresses (user_id, street, city, state) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?);"
        cursor.execute(query, (i, street, city, state))
    connection.commit()
    connection.close()


def main():
    init_tables()
    init_users()
    init_data()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

### main.py

Основная логика

```py
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtSql import QSqlDatabase, QSqlQueryModel
import sqlite3
from hashlib import sha256


class Login(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        self.token = None
        super().__init__(None, Qt.WindowTitleHint | Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.setWindowTitle("Authorization")
        self.textLogin = QLineEdit()
        self.textPassw = QLineEdit()
        self.textPassw.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)
        button = QPushButton("Login")
        button.clicked.connect(self.handle_login)
        layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textLogin)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPassw)
        layout.addWidget(button)
        self.setWindowFlag(Qt.MSWindowsFixedSizeDialogHint)
        #self.resize(self.sizeHint())

    def handle_login(self):
        username = self.textLogin.text()
        connection = sqlite3.connect("users.sqlite")
        query = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username=? and password_hash=?;"
        params = (username, sha256(self.textPassw.text().encode()).hexdigest())
        result = connection.execute(query, params).fetchall()
        connection.close()
        if len(result) != 0:
            self.token = username
            self.accept()
        else:
            QMessageBox.warning(self, "Error", "Bad login or pass")


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, token: str):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("CSM")
        HLayout = QHBoxLayout(self)
        tabs = QTabWidget()
        people_table = QTableView()
        db = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QSQLITE")
        db.setDatabaseName("data.sqlite")
        db.open()
        people_model = QSqlQueryModel()
        people_model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM people;")
        people_table.setModel(people_model)
        people_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        people_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        people_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        people_table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        addresses_table = QTableView()
        addresses_model = QSqlQueryModel()
        addresses_model.setQuery("SELECT * FROM addresses;")
        addresses_table.setModel(addresses_model)
        addresses_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(0, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        addresses_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(1, QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        addresses_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        addresses_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(3, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        addresses_table.horizontalHeader().setSectionResizeMode(4, QHeaderView.Stretch)
        addresses_table.resizeColumnsToContents()

        tabs.addTab(people_table, "People")
        tabs.addTab(addresses_table, "Adresses")
        HLayout.addWidget(tabs)

        VLayout = QVBoxLayout()
        HLayout.addLayout(VLayout)
        connection = sqlite3.connect("users.sqlite")
        query = """
        SELECT
            privileges.privilege
        FROM
            privileges
            JOIN users ON privileges.username = users.username
        WHERE
            users.username = ?;
        """
        params = (token,)
        result = connection.execute(query, params).fetchall()
        connection.close()
        privileges = [_[0] for _ in result]
        VLayout.addWidget(QLabel(token))
        for privilege in privileges:
            VLayout.addWidget(QPushButton(privilege))
        #self.resize(self.sizeHint())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    login = Login()
    if login.exec_() == QDialog.Accepted:
        main = MainWindow(login.token)
        main.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    else:
        sys.exit(0)
```

---

Вкратце:

1. Инициализируем базы данных `python init_db.py`,
2. `python main.py`,
3. Логин `admin` или `viewer`, пароль совпадает с логином.

   ---

   Что имею:
   [image: got1][image: got2]
   Приблизительно то, что хочу получить:
   [image: expected1][image: expected2]
   Т.е., как сделать так, чтобы минимальная *ширина* `QTableView`'ов была такой, чтобы столбцы не обрезались до `...`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все что вам надо сделать - это добавить одну строку:

```
...
addresses_table.setSizeAdjustPolicy(QAbstractScrollArea.AdjustToContents)
...
```

> QAbstractScrollArea::SizeAdjustPolicy
>
> Это перечисление определяет, как подсказка размера QAbstractScrollArea должна корректироваться при изменении размера области просмотра.

Подробнее здесь -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractscrollarea.html#SizeAdjustPolicy-enum

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

Этот пример от `ekhumoro` - гуру PyQt, будет полезен многим,
поэтому я его публикую здесь.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995778/resize-column-width-to-fit-into-the-qtablewidget-pyqt/41003726#41003726

```
import random
from PyQt5.Qt import *

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()

        self.table = QTableWidget(5, 2, self)
        self.button = QPushButton('Обновите таблицу', self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.populate)
        layout = QGridLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.table, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.button, 1, 0)
        layout.setColumnStretch(1, 1)

    def populate(self):
        words = 'Red Green Blue Yellow Black White Purple'.split()
        length = random.randint(2, len(words))
        self.table.setRowCount(random.randint(3, 30))

        for column in range(self.table.columnCount()):
            for row in range(self.table.rowCount()):
                item = QTableWidgetItem(' '.join(
                    random.sample(words, random.randint(1, length))))
                self.table.setItem(row, column, item)

        self.table.setVisible(False)
        self.table.verticalScrollBar().setValue(0)
        self.table.resizeColumnsToContents()
        self.table.setVisible(True)
        self.setTableWidth()

    def setTableWidth(self):
        width = self.table.verticalHeader().width()
        width += self.table.horizontalHeader().length()
        if self.table.verticalScrollBar().isVisible():
            width += self.table.verticalScrollBar().width()
        width += self.table.frameWidth() * 2
        self.table.setFixedWidth(width)

    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        self.setTableWidth()
        super(Window, self).resizeEvent(event)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    window.resize(400, 300)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, я находил это, но это меняет размер таблицы также и по вертикали, что не нужно.

Comment: +Можно уменьшить ширину внешнего окна и столбцы опять обрежутся. Поэтому надо как-то установить *минимальную* ширину. И я вот не знаю, это можно сделать как-то в самих `QTableView` или через внешний `QWidget`.

Comment: QМихаилМуругов  а добавит `addresses_table.setMaximumHeight(200)` не пробовали ?

Comment: Qt, QМихаил, интересная "опечатка" :) Это не совсем то, что нужно, но это не критично. Больше интересует, как установить "нормальную" ширину таблицы, при которой содержимое столбцов не обрезается, минимальной.