# Простая авторизация с логином и паролем

Tags: python, windows, sqlite, qt5

Пишу десктопное приложение для windows на python с помощью QT5. Хочу сделать небольшую авторизация с логином и паролем. Но, увы только начал разбираться в sqllite. Помогите кто чем сможет. Код приветствуется.

Comment: Опубликуйте пожалуйста то, что вы уже написали.

Comment: Там есть авторизация https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1045641/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bc%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-qtableview-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b1%d1%86%d1%8b-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

делал нечто подобное, можете хранить в текстовике данные в виде

```
логин : пароль
```

и добавить в базу столбец, например `person_log`, который является логином пользователя, тогда если логин успешный, выводить те данные, у которых тэг `person_log` равен логину пользователя